# Xcode 7 xib with stackviews not displaying in interface builder after force quit

Tags: ios, xcode, xib

I created a custom cell in an empty xib. As I was working on it, xcode became unresponsive so I force shut it down. The next time I opened xcode, I was surprised to see a blank canvas but my elements are still there. And when I run it on the simulator the tableview cell is still there.

Anyone encountered this error before?

Answer (score 0):

> But my elements are still there

Click one of the element you will see your view.